# LL1 boolean operator Grammar to implement Recursive decent parser

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-construction

Here is the small chunk from original Grammar for which i have to implement the recursive decent parser. We have to remove the ambiguity, left recursion e.t.c from it so that we can implement its parser. I have done the other bits, but can't figure out how to handle the not operator (~).

The valid expression could be.
1 & ~1, (1 & ~1) e.t.c.

I have handle the braces, as well as & and or symbol but can't handle the ~ symbol.

Here is the orginal grammar.

```
A -> A & A 
A -> ~A
A -> (A)
A -> 0 | 1
```

I can't figure out how to handle the **~**.

Here is my solution:

```
one -> two one'
one' -> ~one|^
two -> three two'
two' -> & three two'|^
three -> four three'
three' -> || four three' | ^
four -> (one) |0 |1
```

When i implemented it , everything works fine for brackets, and , or operator . But the negation ~ was not working. So i believe the grammer is not properly converted to LL(1)

Comment: What exactly is holding you back? The fact that it's a prefix operator? Or the ambiguity of parsing `~0 & 1`, maybe?

Comment: I think the issue is that i am not handling the Negation properly. I am taking it as right associative. Have a look at my solution. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have solved it myself after spending quite a lot of time. Here is the solution.

The boolean not or (~) operator has the highest precedence then any other operator in the grammar mentioned above. In the above solution, i was taking its precedence as lower. Here is the proper solution.

[image: Image displaying the solution]